# Column-image hover text

Tags: html, css, masonry

Hello everybody out there reading my question :)

I am currently working on website with a "Masonry-lookalike" home screen.
There are 4x4 images with 2 different sizes and 1 image in every column is hidden.

So far it went pretty good but now I am stuck on the text-effect when hovering one of the images.

When the cursor is `hovering` over an `image`, a small `text-box` should appear on the bottom of it.

- How do i get them one above the other without ruining the Masonry?
- Where do i place the Text in the html code?

Sorry for my English, its not the best since I am from Austria ;)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- HTML -->
<html>
<!-- HEAD -->

<head>
    <!-- STYLESHEET -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- UTF-8 -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<!-- HEAD END -->
<!-- --------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!-- BODY -->

<body>
    <div id="img-container">
        <ul id="content">
            <li><img class="img_a" src="data/placeholder_a.png" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li><img class="img_c" src="data/placeholder_c.png" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li><img class="img_b" src="data/placeholder_b.png" alt="" />
            </li>

            <li><img class="img_a" src="data/placeholder_a.png" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li><img class="img_a" src="data/placeholder_a.png" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li><img class="img_a" src="data/placeholder_a.png" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li><img class="img_c" src="data/placeholder_c.png" alt="" />
            </li>

            <li><img class="img_b" src="data/placeholder_b.png" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li><img class="img_c" src="data/placeholder_c.png" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li><img class="img_a" src="data/placeholder_a.png" alt="" />
            </li>

            <li><img class="img_a" src="data/placeholder_a.png" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li><img class="img_c" src="data/placeholder_c.png" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li><img class="img_b" src="data/placeholder_b.png" alt="" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- BODY END -->

</html>
<!-- HTML END -->
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#img-container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
}
#content {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
#content li img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
/* ---------------------  HOVER EFFECTS  --------------------- */

.img_a:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.img_b:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.img_c:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I will append some zip.-file with .css .html and images.
[Link to Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8q21t2xu3o3p6a/StackOverflowInfoZip.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

The following writeup might help you:

http://geekgirllife.com/place-text-over-images-on-hover-without-javascript/

It is one of the simplest methods I came across. Place the div tag containing text right below the img tag.

Comment: ty for the tip mate :)